# Golang SplitAfter for Regexp type

Tags: regex, go

In golang `strings.SplitAfter` method split text after an special character into an slice, but I didn't find a way for Regexp type to split text after matches. Is there a way to do that?

Example :

```
var text string = "1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9"

res := strings.Split(text, ".")
fmt.Println(res) // print [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

res = strings.SplitAfter(text, ".")
fmt.Println(res) // print [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9]
```

Comment: What is wrong with [`func (*Regexp) Split`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.Split)? Could you please provide some sample input text with the expected output?

Comment: `Split ` remove split character point, but `SplitAfter` just split after split character without character removing

Comment: Ok, I see. As Go regex flavor does not support lookarounds, this could be a really nice feature.

Comment: I means there is no way to do that currently?

Comment: Only using workarounds. E.g., your current result can be achieved by matching all 1+ digits followed with an optional `.`.  See [this demo](https://play.golang.org/p/-6g0mjz02v). Or even any char other than `.` and an optional `.` - `\`[^.]*\.?\``

Answer (score 2):

first at all, your regex `"."` is wrong for `splitAfter` function. You want number followed by value `"."` so the regex is: `"[1-9]"`.

The function you are looking might look like this:

```golang
func splitAfter(s string, re *regexp.Regexp) (r []string) {
    re.ReplaceAllStringFunc(s, func(x string) string {
        s = strings.Replace(s,x,"::"+x,-1)
        return s
    })
    for _, x := range strings.Split(s,"::") {
        if x != "" {
            r = append(r, x)
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Than:

```golang
    fmt.Println(splitAfter("healthyRecordsMetric",regexp.MustCompile("[A-Z]")))
    fmt.Println(splitAfter("healthyrecordsMETetric",regexp.MustCompile("[A-Z]")))
    fmt.Println(splitAfter("HealthyHecord Hetrics",regexp.MustCompile("[A-Z]")))
    fmt.Println(splitAfter("healthy records metric",regexp.MustCompile("[A-Z]")))
    fmt.Println(splitAfter("1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9",regexp.MustCompile("[1-9]")))

[Healthy Records Metric]
[healthy Records Metric]
[healthyrecords M E Tetric]
[Healthy Hecord  Hetrics]
[healthy records metric]
[1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9]
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Regexp type itself does not have a method to do that exactly that but it's quite simple to write a function that implements what your asking based on Regexp functionality:

```
func SplitAfter(s string, re *regexp.Regexp) []string {
    var (
        r []string
        p int
    )
    is := re.FindAllStringIndex(s, -1)
    if is == nil {
        return append(r, s)
    }
    for _, i := range is {
        r = append(r, s[p:i[1]])
        p = i[1]
    }
    return append(r, s[p:])
}
```

[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/L31rgR8apI) I left a program to play with it.